# istream_iterator cin initialization waits for input

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

I've got this code snippet. The istream_iterator object is only defined and not used, so I expect that it won't do anything and application finish immediately. But when I run application, it will not finish before I provide some input. Why?

I'm compiling it on ArchLinux with: gcc 4.7.1, with command: g++ -std=c++11 filename.cpp

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    istream_iterator<char> input(cin);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with C++11, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the standard,

> #### 24.6.1.1 istream_iterator constructors and destructor [istream.iterator.cons]
>
> ```
> istream_iterator(istream_type& s);
> ```
>
> 3 - *Effects*: Initializes *in-stream* with `&s`. *value* may be initialized during construction or the first time it is referenced.

So it is unspecified whether this program will wait for input.

However, it's difficult to see how `istream_iterator` could be implemented otherwise; per 24.6.1:1, *after it is constructed [...] the iterator reads and stores a value of `T`*, so if the read does not occur on construction then it would need to occur on `operator *() const` and on the free `operator==(const istream_iterator<T> &, const istream_iterator<T> &)`, so all of the internal state of the iterator would have to be `mutable`.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, the istream iterator will immediately call `cin >> x` to extract the first token and determine whether it should become equal to the end iterator. The extraction operation blocks until either the stream is closed, a token is extracted or a parsing failure is encountered.

Note that your question title is wrong: You have not only *declared* `input`, but you have also *defined* it. If your code were to reflect the question accurately, it would say

```
extern istream_iterator<char> input;  // declaration only!
```

and there would be no blockage.

Comment: [`The actual read operation is performed when the iterator is incremented, not when it is dereferenced. The first object may be read when the iterator is constructed or when the first dereferencing is done.`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)

Comment: @BoBTFish: Indeed. There's no way around it if you think about it, since you have to know whether or not you're at the end: `input == istream_iterator<char>()` has to give the correct answer.

Comment: All definitions are also declarations (but not vice versa). I wouldn't say the title was wrong.

Comment: @sftrabbit: Sure, but just to be pedantic, it's not the declaration that blocks (which would be odd, because a declaration is just a piece of grammar), but the definition (which is actual executable code). It'd be like calling a question "Error above `main()`". True, but not very specific.

Comment: @sftrabbit you're both wrong; it's the initialization that blocks.  I've corrected the title and clarified the question (hopefully without changing the intent).

Comment: @ecatmur: Yes, of course - the definition entails the initialization, though! :-)

Comment: @ecatmur I suppose I interpreted it as "the declaration in my code example blocks" which *is* true. In a general sense though, I agree.

Answer (score 2):

From a stream, you can only "get" every value once, after that it's gone. However, a common need for iterators is to access a value multiple times without incrementing the iterator. As such, the `istream_iterator` will extract the first value on construction and copy it into an internal value which is then returned when dereferencing the iterator.
This also allows the iterator to determine whether it's at the end of input and become an end iterator. On incrementing, the next value is then read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istream_iterator<int> start(cin);
    istream_iterator<int> itend;

    while( start != itend ) {
        cout << *start << endl;
        start++;
        //Press Enter followed by Control-D on linux to exit the loop
    }

    cout<<"Control-D Pressed "<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just remember it closes the input stream.